# FormatString for a TextBoxFor() in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textbox

- How to specify MaxLength for a
  textbox , Like MaxLenth="18"
- How to Set the TextBox Format String 
  as FormatString="$###,###,###,##0.00"
  in model so even if i enter 100 it should automatically become $100.00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to specify MaxLength for a textbox , Like MaxLenth="18"

You could pass additional html attributes to the `TextBoxFor` method:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeValue, new { maxlength = "18" })
```

> How to Set the TextBox Format String as FormatString="$###,###,###,##0.00" in model so even if i enter 100 it should automatically become $100.00

You could use the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:$###,###,###,##0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? Value { get; set; }
```

and then:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Value) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the maxlength.But [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:$###,###,###,##0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? Value { get; set; } is not working , its not at all formating as desired.

Comment: @Basavaraj, did you use `Html.EditorFor(x => x.Value)` in your view instead of `Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value)`? The `DisplayFormat` attribute applies only when using the `EditorFor` helper.